# How to switch the paragraph direction to rtl on Lexical Editor?

Tags: lexicaljs

I only found a function that returns the diraction that called `$isParentElementRTL(selection)`
I want to add a button that switches the direction of a paragraph between rtl => ltr and from ltr => rtl

Note: The app is a React app